# Formato de ponto flutuante em java

Tags: java

Pessoal como leio um ponto flutuante com um limite especifíco de casas decimais  após a vírgula? Por exemplo, ler o valor 3.14?

Observação: sei que da para formatar o valor de uma variável com o decimal format, mas preciso receber valores com apenas duas casas decimais já na leitura.

Comment: Por limite específico de casas decimais, você quer dizer que serão sempre duas? Como você está lendo essa valor? O usuário entra ele via Scanner?

Comment: O único metódo que conheco é via Scanner, e sim, as leituiras sempre seguem um padrão de quantidade, por exemplo, valores com 2 casas após a virgula.

Comment: Ok quanto a isso. Outro ponto, você disse "preciso receber valores com apenas duas casas decimais já na leitura" isso quer dizer que se a pessoa digitar `3.142` é para ler apenas `3.14`? Ou deve acontecer algo de diferente caso a entrada não seja do jeito que você precisa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazer isso com uma combinação de [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) e [Double.parseDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)). Eu criei um Double customizado chamado FormattedDouble que extende DecimalFloat para realizar o que você quer. Veja o código da classe:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

public class FormattedDouble extends DecimalFormat {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DecimalFormatSymbols symbols;
    private String stringValue;
    private double value;

    public FormattedDouble(double value) {
        super("#.##"); // Customize the format here.
        symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
        setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        this.setStringValue(format(value));
        this.setValue(Double.parseDouble(this.getStringValue()));
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public void setStringValue(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

}
```

Isto posto, obter um Double com o número de casas limitadas (Utilizando o exemplo que deu), é simples:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double example = new FormattedDouble(3.1412233).getValue(); // Returns 3.14.
        System.out.println(example); // Outputs 3.14.
    }

}
```

Você pode adaptar a classe FormattedDouble pra permitir alterações na quantidade de casas. Leia a documentação do [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) pra poder adaptar às suas necessidades.

EDIT:

Não é **exatamente** o que você quer, porque não é possível. Um Double é um Double, e ponto (Se quer **alterar o formato**, precisa ***formatar***). É possível simular o que você quer, a alteração no "momento da leitura", criando um Double customizado, como eu fiz.